# Can async-await be available in other .NET languages besides C#?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, async-await

The [async-await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) pattern is one of the more powerful additions to .NET 4.5 and C# 5.0

It is currently only available in C# and VB as far as I know.

Is this API a feature of the .NET CLR or of the C# compiler itself?

What I'm really asking is this - should we expect async/await in the other .NET languages such as:

- C++ (via C++/CLI)
- Python (via IronPython)
- PHP (via Phalanger)
- JavaScript (via IronJS)

Please note I'm not asking about asynchronous programming in general, but about the specifics of the async-await pattern (asynchronous code which is written **synchronously**).

Comment: It's an extremely complicated compiler feature, with a small amount of supporting BCL API.  See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction.aspx

Comment: http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/

Comment: Just an FYI, F# has supported async operations as a language feature for longer than C# and VB, in an arguably (or obviously ;) more powerful way. See http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx

Comment: For JavaScript, see [this blog article](http://jlongster.com/A-Study-on-Solving-Callbacks-with-JavaScript-Generators).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this API a feature of the .NET CLR or of the C# compiler itself?

This is a feature of the compiler.  There were no CLR changes required to support `async` and `await`.  Other languages would need to be extended to support it.  There is nothing preventing a compiler from doing this, but it would have to be changed in the compiler and language itself.

C++ does support some [asynchrony in Windows Store applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx) via `task`/`then`, though it's not as usable as the `async`/`await` keywords in C# and VB.

> It is currently only available in C# and VB as far as I know

Note that F# also has `async` support (which predates the C# and VB.Net versions by quite a bit).  It is different than the C# style async support, but similar (and inspired the C# and VB.Net teams).

Comment: Since async-await was ported to Mono, did they port the compilation itself or are they relying on a Microsoft compiler?

Comment: @talkol They implemented it themselves in Mono's compiler.  It's just a translation to a state machine based on some defined rules.  There was no CLR support changes required.

Comment: If they ported the compilation themselves, how could they do it so quickly? This entire pattern seems like a very big effort by some excellent engineers in MS. I wouldn't have expected it to be reproduced so easily

Comment: @talkol You were linked to a blog article that Jon Skeet published in which he describes how to implement much of it.  That came out well before C# 5.0 was released; it's based on the beta version.

Comment: @talkol It's actually built on top of a lot of what existed in the BCL in .NET 4.  The trickiest part was designing the approach - reimplementing it once the approach exists is complex, but not horrible, as it's basically just a large state machine.

Comment: Can't wait to see it in other non .NET languages. It's quite a remarkable evolution of software engineering in general

Comment: @talkol Unfortunately, it requires changing the language itself.  As such, I doubt it will happen in the languages you list until such time as the normal implementation's of those languages provide some form of async support (since the .NET versions try to match the normal language syntax).  You never know if or when that could happen, though

Comment: I expect other languages (completely unrelated to .net) to implement these ideas soon, I've already seen "jealous" discussions in the Java and python communities :)

Answer (score 2):

The C# and VB.Net compilers implement the `await` pattern by transforming the original method into a state machine.  This is very similar to say how the F# async / work flow pattern works.  This type of transformation is possible in any language that targets the CLR.

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of the compiler that requires BCL support.

For example, there is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) that allows you to use it from .NET 4.0 by adding the various APIs (e.g. [Task.GetAwaiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter.aspx)) that the language support leverages.

It's conceptually similar to yield return, which is another compiler feature that any language could conceivably implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the  [Visual C++ Compiler November 2013 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151), some nifty examples to do things like:
    __await FileIO::WriteTextAsync(file, file->Name);

It doesn't look as nice yet, and it is likely the standard evolving, new and better (at least standard) ways to do this will emerge in future versions.