# how to avoid Server busy window if used thread.join() in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, interop

I have a `c++ application` and use `clr` to call the below `c# method`. Everything is going good except for one thing. As `wpf window` needs `STA thread`, I'm trying to create a new thread with STA state and start it. This makes the wpf window `modeless`, even if the window is started with `show dialog`. So I tried using `thread.join()` to make the caller thread to wait until the thread completes or window closes. using `thread.join()` shows `server busy window` after a few seconds. (I'm not doing any operation related to the internet in my application).

How to make the caller thread to `wait` until the window closes? or How to get rid of Server busy window?

```
        void ShowWindow()
        {
            _ownerHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                MyWpfWindow window = new MyWpfWindow();
                MyWpfWindowViewModel vm = new MyWpfWindowViewModel();

                WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
                helper.Owner = _ownerHandle;

                window.DataContext = vm;

                window.ShowDialog();

            }));

            // set the apartment state  this will only invoke the WPF window  
            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
            // start the thread  
            newWindowThread.Start();
            //waits this thread here untill the newWindowThread execution completes.
            newWindowThread.Join();

        }
```

Also, I tried with a while loop as below to block the current main thread.

```
while(!windowShown)
{
}
```

in the place of newWindowThread.join(). After using this, my window is not visible.

I'm getting a server busy window as below

[image]

Comment: Did you try to subclass `System.Window.Application`, configure it to use your Wpf window, and then call `Run()` on it?  This is the proper way to boot a WPF Window.

Comment: Spawning a thread only to `Join it is kinda pointless

Comment: while (newWindowThread.IsAlive)
            {
                newWindowThread.Join(2000);
            }  
this solved my issue. now i'm not getting the server busy window also it behaves like blocking the current thread. Is it the way to block an MFC thread?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Join()` blocks the current thread. If you want to wait asynchronously, you could use a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
static async Task ShowWindowAsync()
{
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    _ownerHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        MyWpfWindow window = new MyWpfWindow();
        MyWpfWindowViewModel vm = new MyWpfWindowViewModel();
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
        helper.Owner = _ownerHandle;
        window.DataContext = vm;
        window.Closed += (s, e) =>
        {
            semaphore.Release();
            semaphore.Dispose();
        };
        window.ShowDialog();

    }));

    // set the apartment state  this will only invoke the WPF window  
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    // start the thread  
    newWindowThread.Start();
    //waits this thread here untill the newWindowThread execution completes.
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
}
```

Comment: Still my main thread showing 'server busy' window when i use SemaphoreSlim

Comment: @S.FrankRicharrd: How are you calling the `ShowWindowAsync()` method then? Make sure that you await it.

Comment: i can't await since that method is getting called from c++\cli, so i use task.wait() like, ShowWindowAsync().wait()

Comment: @S.FrankRicharrd: Then you are blocking as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274911/how-to-consume-an-awaitable-in-c-cli).

Comment: i can get my desired output when i try to use Application.run(window) but i can't create or run the same window again.

Comment: You can only create one instance of the `Application` class per AppDomain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189689/discussion-between-s-frank-richarrd-and-mm8).